# algorithm for geo application

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have an application that displays the nearest gas station for users while they are driving cars . now i can display the top 10 nearest gas stations . what i want to build also is to display a View that shows the distance between the user current location and nearest gas station between the top 10 that i collect from Database i.e the first one .
what i thought about it

```
1- The GPS provide a new location to my application.

2- run an SQL query to get the top 10 gas stations in a Circle that it center is the user location and it radius is 2 km.

3- calculate the distance between the current location and the first gas station returned from the Query above (which is the nearest one) .

4- display that distance to user.
```

now why i dont think this is not good , since the gps provider may be late to provide a new location since i filter them to be within a 200m accuracy . and i do an I/O operation which may take long time to go back. all of this will result in a fixed distance between the user and the nearest gas station and wait for the update .

please note the following

1- that i build indexes for the columns i used in the query to speed up and prevent full scan issue.

2-this is how i defined my request to updates to get update of location ASAP. `this.mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, this.mLocationListener);`

is there a faster approach to do this ?

Comment: Well, you could query a larger radius and only re-query the database once the car approached the circumference of your search area. Whether such a strategy is worth the extra effort probably depends on whether you are using a local database or making an over-the-air query.

Answer (score 0):

There are approaches 1000 times faster.
Why a horrible slow sql? In embedded systems sql is not the best option.
Read all the gas stations in memory (array). At least the coordinates and the station id.

A simple soultion: Make a brute force search and calculate all distances, keep the nearest
When you found the nearest station, then you could query the sql for adress, name etc.

If you have more than 10.000 stations than you probably need a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use some database, I would recommend mongoDB - no SQL database.
It has the GeoIndex with "near" function.

This can get very high read performance, and you do not need to invent the wheel.

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing